# Upon a click, how do I set an event handler to fire on a subsequent click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I have a piece of JavaScript using jQuery that looks a bit like this:

```
$('.myclass').on('click', function() {
   // Do Stuff
   $(document).on('click.mynamespace', function() {
       // Do More Stuff
       $(document).off('click.mynamespace');
   });
});
```

Upon a click on `.myclass`, I am expecting it to Do Stuff, then attach a handler to the click event on the document and Do More Stuff on a *subsequent* click - but it appears that both Stuff and More Stuff happen on the first click.

Is the click event still firing when the second event handler is attached? How do I achieve my desired effect?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `stopPropagation` to prevent the event from bubbling out to the document on the first click:

```
$('.myclass').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // Do Stuff
    $(document).on('click.mynamespace', function() {
        // Do More Stuff
        $(document).off('click.mynamespace');
    });
});
```